# What progress has been made to prove whether or not p=np?

Tags: np-hardness, open-problem, np, proofs

I know that it is still one of the biggest mysteries of computer science whether non-deterministically polynomial problems can be solved in polynomial time.  I am curious to know what makes this problem so difficult to prove/disprove.  Has there been any progress has been made toward resolving it.  That is, what approaches have been taken (and failed), and what insights have been made toward possibly finding a solution?

Comment: geometric complexity theory by Mulmuley is one of them..

Comment: "I have not failed. I have just found ten thousand ways that won’t work." "How long will it take to find your shoes?"

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested in Scott Aaronson's talk "[Has There Been Progress on the P vs. NP Question?](http://www.scottaaronson.com/talks/pvsnpcsw.ppt)" ([earlier version](http://www.scottaaronson.com/talks/pvsnp.ppt))

Answer (score 5):

For what concern "... what approaches have been taken and (in all probability) **failed** ...", see the [P-versus-NP Page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm) that collects links to papers/authors that try to settle the "P versus NP" question (in either way) :-)